# How to write Antlr rules in a non-recursive way?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have the following the expressions I need to parse

```
and(true, false)
or(true, false, true)
not(or(true, false, true))
and(and(true, false), false)
or(or(true, false, true), true)
```

so far I have the following grammar

```
expr
    : orExpr
    ;

orExpr
    : OR '(' andExpr (',' andExpr)+ ')'
    | andExpr
    ;

andExpr
    : AND '(' equalityExpr (',' equalityExpr)+ ')'
    | equalityExpr
    ;

equalityExpr
    : comparison ((EQUALS | NOT_EQUALS) comparison)*
    ;

comparison
    : notExpr ((GREATER_THAN_EQUALS | LESS_THAN_EQUALS | GREATER_THAN | LESS_THAN ) notExpr)?
    ;

notExpr
    : NOT '(' expr ')'
    | primary
    ;

primary
    : '(' expr ')'
    | true
    | false
    ;
```

I am not able to parse `and(and(true, false), false)` with the above grammar? where am I going wrong?

Please assume there is precedence between `AND` `OR` `NOT` (although I understand it may look not necessary)

Comment: It looks like this is still a (small) part of the actual language you're trying to parse. Could you edit your question to include a complete expression with all possible operators? Your question as it now stands can be answered with changing to `OR '(' expr (',' expr)+ ')'` and `AND '(' expr (',' expr)+ ')'`, but I doubt that will resolve all your issues. Your call.

Comment: vow! That solves most of it. Sure added the comparison rule as well. I am just trying to simplify the scope! Now I am unable to parse `true=and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2)` or vice-versa `and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2)=true`

Comment: `I am just trying to simplify the scope`, I understand, but by doing so, you're (quite possibly) leaving out information that others need to give you a good answer.

Comment: comparison rule is the final one I got. if I add more in the future and if I am unable to solve it I will have to post another question. But for now, I need to be able to parse true=and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2) or vice-versa and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2)=true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But for now, I need to be able to parse `true=and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2)` or vice-versa `and(5=5, 4=4, 3>2)=true` ?

In that case, there is absolutely no need to complicate things. All you have to do is this:

```
grammar Test;

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : '(' expr ')'
 | OR '(' expr (',' expr)+ ')'
 | AND '(' expr (',' expr)+ ')'
 | NOT '(' expr ')'
 | expr (LT | LTE | GT | GTE) expr
 | expr (EQ | NEQ) expr
 | TRUE
 | FALSE
 | INT
 ;

LT    : '<';
LTE   : '<=';
GT    : '>';
GTE   : '>=';
NEQ   : '!=';
EQ    : '=';
NOT   : 'not';
TRUE  : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
AND   : 'and';
OR    : 'or';

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

Comment: This makes sense. Can you please shine some light on when one would try to do things in a non-recursive way? I thought recursive is all bad!

Comment: No, it is not all bad. Note that the way you did it already was recursive. What you probably mean is _direct left recursion_. This also is not bad, but most parser generators don't support this (it is new in ANTLR4). So, since it _is_ supported in ANTLR4, mind as well use it since it greatly simplifies your grammar.

Comment: I don't even know if it is even possible to do in a non-recursive way? that is in fact one of my questions

Comment: Not if you want an arbitrary amount of nesting in your expressions.

Comment: well, your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184169/can-left-recursion-be-eliminated-in-all-cases-in-antlr/60185203 allows an arbitrary amount of nesting without recursion. so I am not sure how to interpret you statement "Not if you want an arbitrary amount of nesting in your expressions."

Comment: For sure it uses recursion. Not direct left recursive rules, but it uses recursion: the `primary` rule has an `expr` rule in it. It (the `primary` rule) would be left recursive if it matched an `expr` immediately, without the `'('` in front of it. Checkout this doc: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/left-recursion.md